# Apache Spark insert multiple rows into the DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

First of all I'm bound to the `Java 1.7` and `Java Spark 1.6`

I have a lot of columns and data but let's follow the simple example.
So let's say I have the simple table (DataFrame)

```
+----+-------+
|  id|   name|
+----+-------+
|   1|      A|
+----+-------+
|   2|      B|
+----+-------+
|   3|      C|
+----+-------+
```

Every time on the each cell I'm calling custom udf function for the calculations that are needed. One of the requirements is to create and append the new N rows every time after each row (or after the each row that has some kind of the value).

So, it's like:

```
+----+-------+
|  id|   name|
+----+-------+
|   1|      A| --> create 1 new Row (based on the udf calculations)
+----+-------+
|   2|      B| --> create 2 new Rows (based on the udf calculations)
+----+-------+
|   3|      C|
+----+-------+
```

Expected result is:

```
+----+-------+
|  id|   name|
+----+-------+
|   1|      A|
+----+-------+
|    |  (new)|
+----+-------+
|   2|      B|
+----+-------+
|    |  (new)|
+----+-------+
|    |  (new)|
+----+-------+
|   3|      C|
+----+-------+
```

My missunderstaning - what is the best/correct way to do it?
The current issues that I faced: approach via `dataFrame.foreach(new Function1<Row, BoxedUnit>() {...})`  <-- not a functional interface; no java8; have to implement the whole interface; code structure is complicated - always receiving `Serializable error`.
Personally I am not sure that `foreach` is the best way to do it but I have somehow to iterate over the current dataFrame.

Also if I got it right I will have always to apply `unionAll` for appending new rows.
Maybe there any other better ways to do this through the `Spark Sql` or transforming this into `RDD` etc.

Comment: I'd suggest returning an array from the UDF, and then exploding the array to multiple rows

Comment: Yes, inside the UDF I will save the result of the computations into the temp column so I will be able to take it during the iteration. But still the iteration by itself is unclear for me. Thank you.

Comment: no iteration is needed. just do something like `df.select(col("id"),col("name"),explode(my_udf("id","name")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question (thanks @mck for the idea with the `explode()`)

So, let's say the initial df is:

```
DataFrame baseDf = ...

+----+-------+
|  id|   name|
+----+-------+
|   1|      A|
+----+-------+
|   2|      B|
+----+-------+
```

Create new 'temp' coulmn for the UDF result and save into new separate df:

```
DataFrame df1 = dataFrame.withColumn("temp")

+----+-------+-----+
|  id|   name| temp|
+----+-------+-----+
|   1|      A|     |
+----+-------+-----+
|   2|      B|     |
+----+-------+-----+
```

From UDF return a list (or a map):

```
+----+-------+------+
|  id|   name|  temp|
+----+-------+------+
|   1|      A| [C,D]|
+----+-------+------+
|   2|      B| [E,F]|
+----+-------+------+
```

Apply `explode()` on the temp column and move it to the new dataframe:

```
DataFrame unfolded = df1.select(functions.col("id"), functions.explode(new Column("temp")).as("name"))

+----+-------+
|  id|   name|
+----+-------+
|   1|      C|
+----+-------+
|   1|      D|
+----+-------+
|   2|      E|
+----+-------+
|   2|      F|
+----+-------+
```

Now, since the structure of the `unfolded` and `baseDf` is the same we can apply `unionAll` and then sort or filter as we need:

```
baseDf = baseDf.unionAll(unfolded).sort("id", "name"):

+----+-------+
|  id|   name|
+----+-------+
|   1|      A|
+----+-------+
|   1|      C|
+----+-------+
|   1|      D|
+----+-------+
|   2|      B|
+----+-------+
|   2|      E|
+----+-------+
|   2|      F|
+----+-------+
```

New fields were added.